# How do I designate more than one category in this Wordpress hack?

Tags: php, wordpress

am excluding comments from specific categories. However, when I try to exclude more than one, it doesn't work.

This works: `<?php if (!in_category('7')) comments_template(); ?>`

This does not work:

`<?php if (!in_category('7 , 9')) comments_template(); ?>`

or

`<?php if (!in_category('7')) comments_template(); ?> <?php if (!in_category('9')) comments_template(); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has a pretty decent documentation that is always worth looking into first. See [Function Reference:  in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

The function does not seem to accept multiple arguments, so you'll have to do this in PHP:

```
if ((!in_category('7')) and (!in_category('9')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( !in_category('7') && !in_category('9') ) {
  comments_template();
}
?>
```